# Don't understand coefficients in MATLAB "butter" low pass result

Tags: matlab, filters, lowpass-filter

I don't unstand the nature of the output in Matlab's "butter" command. Calling

```
[b,a] = butter(4, 0.5, 'low');
```

gives me two vectors, which the documentation says are `b` for numerator, and `a` for denominator, of the transfer function.

However plotting the frequency response of this transfer function with `freqz()` does not give me what I expected.

If I plot

```
freqz(b./a)
```

I see:

[image: freqz of b over a]

This is not a low pass filter, this is some sort of band stop filter suppressing the middle frequencies. However if I plot

```
freqz(b)
```

I see what looks like the low pass filter I was hoping for:

[image: freqz of b only]

So if I want to use a Butterworth filter to low pass my data, do I only use `b`? And if so what is the point of `a`?

Comment: Correct: freqz(b,a), i.e., you should supply both the numerator and denominator to freqz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax. You should call `freqz` function as:

```
freqz(b,a)
```

You do not divide any coefficients. In case of non-recursive filters (FIR) you use only coefficients stored in `b` vector. When you are using the recursive LCCDE (*Linear Constant Coefficients Difference Equation*) (mostly IIR filters) then you need also the `a` vector. I suggest you to set `a` to 1 if you use non-recursive FIR filters.

You should also watch out for numerical problems with transfer function representation as mentioned in final paragraph of this [*manual entry*](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html) and [*this answer*](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/17986/8202). It's always safer to use z-p-k representation.

Comment: That is: RTGM!!!

Comment: I always say: if you want to learn MATLAB, there is no better source than F1. They have the best manual ever.

Comment: Blimey, I wasn't doing my division in the Fourier domain. Now I see why that doesn't work!